# scrollview inside another scrollview is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have added vertical scrollview to another existing vertical scrollview in Layout(xml) file. But it is not working. Only outer scrollview is working .

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/outer_linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/blue_bg_layout_sa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebg_320_568">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_img_view_sa"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo_home_250_150"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/claim_tiles_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/logo_img_view_sa">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/windshield_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/windshield_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/windshield_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/windshield"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/windshield_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/windshield_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pdr_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pdr_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pdr_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/pdr"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/pdr_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/pdr_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tire_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tire_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tire_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/pdr"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/tire_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/tire_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wheel_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/wheel_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wheel_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/wheel"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/wheel_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/wheel_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/key_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/key_replacement_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/key_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/key"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/key_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/key_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gap_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gap_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gap_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/gap"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/gap_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/gap_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/interior_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/interior_protection_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/interior_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/interior"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/interior_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/interior_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/exterior_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/exterior_protection_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exterior_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/exterior"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/exterior_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/exterior_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/theft_btn"
                android:layout_height="87dp"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/theft_105_87"
                android:onClick="showClaimForm"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/theft_btn_lbl"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:text="@string/theft"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/theft_btn"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/theft_btn"
                android:textSize="@dimen/system12"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Please provide help with proper answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not supposed to use nested scrollview, it is against the design principles.

Comment: you put scroll view a scroll view that's strange

Comment: Why you want to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it!

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) says:

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll

If you try it, you should get this exception:

```
IllegalStateException "Scrollview can host only one direct child"
```

One solution can be to add a `LinearLayout` as a direct child and then put the other `ScrollView` inside it.

Comment: i have placed  only one direct child in the scrollview .You can see in code. thanks.

Comment: But it is not a good practice too. It not make sense: how can android determine which ScrollView you are scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Add "android:fillViewport" to attribute to your parent ScrollView and set it to true. So they look like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: You can try replaccing the inner ScrollView with listview and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide scrolling within scrollable view.
This applies to all views.
E.g.
1.ScrollView As Parent and LisView as child or vice versa.
2.ScrollView as Parent and GridView as child or vice versa.
3.ScrollView within ScrollView.

#### Solution:-

The Only Solution to This Scrolling Problem is:--

-->You need to Calculate the Inner ScrollView's Length and make it that large.